# Robot Code not working in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void save() {
        robot = getRobotInstance();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

        robot.delay(4000);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        robot.delay(3000);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(3000);

    }
```

My Robot code is not working when I am trying to save PDF. This is the code that I have written to save the PDF, please can someone suggest me what should be done

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the help center on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Hey it won't work to save pdf in web view.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need the context on saving pdf file. If the pdf file is in the web page and you need to Save it to local machine, then we have some solution for that:
- Reconfig the browser so that the file will be save automatically to the disk without opening Confirmation Dialog.
- Update the Robot code (or autoIT script) to save the file from the dialog.